# Static code analysis tool for terraform

Tags: static-analysis, terraform

Is there any static code analysis tool for terraform? I tried tflint. But it doesn't support output of module or attributes of resources. any other suggestion please

Comment: What are you wanting out of the static analysis?

Comment: https://blog.christophetd.fr/shifting-cloud-security-left-scanning-infrastructure-as-code-for-security-issues/#Comparison

Answer (score 5):

[Terrascan](https://github.com/cesar-rodriguez/terrascan) is another static analysis tool in addition to [TFLint](https://github.com/wata727/tflint). Terrascan is more focused on security checks for AWS resources.

Answer (score 4):

[Checkov](https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov/) is another terraform static analysis tool. Scanning multi-cloud resources for security miss configurations and supports `terraform>=0.12`

Answer (score 2):

There is also [TFsec](https://github.com/tfsec/tfsec), which is pretty good.

I'm working on a product that allows you to try a bunch of these scanners pretty easily and help integrate with your CI/CD called [Soluble](https://get.soluble.cloud/) to determine which scanner works best for your environment. Always appreciate feedback.

Answer (score -2):

you may also checkout enterprise grade solutions (google you will find them) similar to aquasec solution.
I would create a comparison table, pros and cons and then consider the best.